Reconstruct orientations of a cobot end effector from the trajectory positions
I have a an excel datasheet for a cobot's end effector, however for my project I want to reconstruct the orientation of the end-effector of my cobot using the translation data alone, i.e.  x, y and z positions. So far I got the normal at each point and I am trying to reconstruct the orientation using the below algo:
def NormalToQuaternion(n1, n2):
    theta = np.arccos(np.dot(n1,n2))
    u = np.array(np.cross(n1, n2))
    u = u/np.linalg.norm(u)
    w = np.array([np.cos(theta/2)])
    q_vec = np.sin(theta/2)*u
    # q = np.append(q_vec, w)
    q = np.append(w , q_vec)
    return q

q = np.zeros((len(Normal), 4))
for i in range(0, len(Normal)-1):
    # n1 = Normal[i,:]
    n1 = np.array([0,0,1])
    n2 = Normal[i+1,:]

    orientation = NormalToQuaternion(n1, n2)
    q[i, :] = orientation

The Normal in the code contains the normal direction to the trajectory at each point.
This however, doesn't give the desirable plot on comparison with the original data. How should I proceed?
